# Row Number In oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to fetch data based on the last row number.

[image]

I want the records highlighted in yellow color. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Should be a simple `MAX` function.

```
select max(row_number) rn, 
       account_no
from your_table
group by account_no
order by account_no;
```

---

If "row_number" represents the result of analytic function (which isn't clear from what you posted so far), then include `ORDER BY` clause into the function (I don't know which column you're sorting data on) in **descending** order so that your "max" actually becomes "min" whose `RN = 1` and then it is easy to select it as a final result.

```
with temp as
  (select columnb, 
          columnc,
          row_number() over (partition by accountno order by SOMETHING desc) rn
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                    add this
   from some_table
  )
select columnb, 
       columnc
from temp
where rn = 1
```

---

As I don't have your tables, here's Scott's EMP:

```
SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        920                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.81       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.81       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.81      10000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

14 rows selected.
```

Your code would then be like this; note line #6 which calculates row number as I suggested; you'll use it in the final `WHERE` clause (line #11), while presenting that "max" row number value you desperately wanted.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select deptno,
  3            sal,
  4            row_number() over (partition by deptno order by sal) rn,
  5            --
  6            row_number() over (partition by deptno order by sal desc) rnd
  7     from emp
  8    )
  9  select deptno, sal, rn
 10  from temp
 11  where rnd = 1
 12  /

    DEPTNO        SAL         RN
---------- ---------- ----------
        10      10000          3
        20       3000          4
        30       2850          6

SQL>
```

Comment: Using row_number as analytical function ... so with that can't use simply max function. The query that I am using is like this - SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUTNO), COLUMN B,COLUMN C, COLUMN D, COLUMN E  FROM TABLE_NAME;  and all the fields are imp.... so on the basis query how it would be possible to get the records that are highlighted in yellow in above question.

Comment: Why didn't you say so in the first place? I added some more info; have a look.

Comment: Still I will not get that data because u have mention the condition where rn = 1....want that data which is highlighted in yellow...

Comment: Works for me, at least the way I understood the problem. If that's not what you want, please, post CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data and desired output; I'll have a look, then.